# AddClass/RemoveClass jQuery 2.x

Tags: jquery

I have a set of hyperlinks that act as buttons that are direct children of a div.  When the user clicks one of the links/buttons, it sets the class to 'active' and when they click another link/button it removes the active class, sets that button to inactive and then sets active on the link/button the user actually clicked.

The problem is I also need to be able to de-select a link/button if the user clicks the **same button**, basically like a toggle.  I can't seem to integrate that into my code.  Can someone use what I have below and add to it a way to toggle the class if the user clicks the same button/link instead of a different one?

```
$('#divResponses a').on('click', function(){

 $(this).closest('div').find('a').removeClass('active').addClass('notActive') ;
 $(this).removeClass('notActive').addClass('active');

}

--html--
<div id="divResponses">
 <a href="" class="btn notActive">Button1</a>
 <a href="" class="btn notActive">Button2</a>
 <a href="" class="btn notActive">Button3</a>
 <a href="" class="btn notActive">Button4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you really need both classes `active` and `notActive`? Isn't `notActive` the same as not having the `active` class?

Comment: I use the notActive class as a way to do styling, that's the main reason

Comment: `:not(.active)` will do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

I would use toggleClass and use siblings to target the rest of the links:

```
$(this).toggleClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you need to define an id for each button? Like so:

```
<a href="" id="1" class="btn notActive">Button1</a>
<a href="" id="2" class="btn notActive">Button2</a>
<a href="" id="3" class="btn notActive">Button3</a>
```

And then proceed to check if the same button is clicked twice using that id?

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify the HTML:

```
<div id="divResponses">
 <a href="#" class="btn active">Button1</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn">Button2</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn ">Button3</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn ">Button4</a>
</div>
```

Assuming the default state of the link is `notActive` so a special class for that may not really be necessary. just style the `.btn` class accordingly. If you want a link to be active by default, add the `.active` class to it.

Then toggle the active class....

```
$('#divResponses a').on('click', function(){
    $('#divResponses a').removeClass('active'); //Removes any active class on other links
   $(this).toggleClass('active'); //toggles active on the click element
});
```

If you *do not* want to deactivate previously clicked links then:

```
$('#divResponses a').on('click', function(){
       $(this).toggleClass('active'); //toggles active on the click element
    });
```

## [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/rdz4xpn9/2/)

If you want to keep your `notActive` class : [jsFiddle demo for that](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/rdz4xpn9/3/)

Comment: I looked at this jsFiddle, and if you click button 3 for example, and then click button 3 again, it doesn't de-select... that's the concern.

Comment: This answer is merely to point you in a good direction. It's not my intent to write complete, usable code for your specific situation. You'll need to adjust as necessary.

Comment: So my code already does what you created in the jsFiddle.  So while I appreciate you providing a possible solution, I was hoping to solve the problem with clicking the same button/link and having it toggle the active class